# Missing Colours in the combined plot by 'ggarrange'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am combining 4 plots using `ggarrange` but out of all the colours in the individual plots:

[image: See Here]

I only get two colours in the combined plot (red and black)

[image: See Here]

Is there a way to preserve all the colours in the combined plot?

Here is the function to make the individual plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
ward.graph <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...){
    ggplot(df,aes(x = year, y = remained, fill=as.factor(dplyr::desc(v)))) + 
    geom_area(stat="identity", colour="black", width=1.2) +
    labs(x="", y="", title=paste("ward", df$ward)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2020, 2050, by = 5)) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))  +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.6), angle=90)) +
    theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(0.6))) +
    theme(plot.title =element_text(size=rel(0.6))) +
    theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust =0.1)) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Vintages",ncol=18))  +
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8))+
    theme(legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))  +
    theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black")) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom")+
    theme(legend.position="bottom",
    plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,-0.2,0), "cm"))
  }
vy1 <- subset(vy, vy$ward==1 & vy$type=="APARTMENT")
p1<- ward.graph(vy1)
print(p1)

type0="APARTMENT"
city_name="Calgary"
type_title="Apartments"
```

Loop to make all the plots:

```
library(gridExtra)
plot_list = list()
for(i in 1:4) {
  vy1 <- subset(vy, vy$ward==i & vy$type==type0)
  plot_list[[i]]<- ward.graph(vy1)
}
```

Here I am combining the plots:

```
  install.packages("ggpubr")
  library(ggpubr)
  figure<- grid.draw(ggarrange(plot_list[[1]],plot_list[[2]],plot_list[[3]],
          plot_list[[4]],
          common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom"))

annotate_figure(figure,
                top = text_grob(paste("Number of",type_title,"in",city_name,sep=" "), 
                                color = "red", face = "bold", size = 10))
```

Here is some of my data:

```
> dput(head(vy1))
    structure(list(year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), v = c(1990, 1991, 
1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 
1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 
1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 
1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 
1994), ward = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4), remained = c(4897.50570492114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3143.11565640186, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2550.6593359167, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4358.00079250633, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 4894.18607808419, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3140.98519005566, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2548.9304482556, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4355.04685283624, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 4888.8318412504, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3137.54895401342, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2546.14191976995, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4350.28243401351, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4880.4658461976, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3132.1798351974, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2541.78484401111, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 4342.83802960301, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -80L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What package is `ggarrange` from? Also, do you really need an example with 14 (!) subplots to make your issue reproducible? Please make your example reproducible with the sample data you give (sample data seems to be only for one subplot?).

Comment: 'ggarrange' is from the `ggpubr` package. I have also corrected the other issues.

Comment: It looks the black geom_area borders are too thick, covering up the fill area. The `size` parameter in geom_area will fix this.

Comment: Even with the edits, I cannot reproduce the problem with the given dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the geom_area borders are too thick. Here's how to adjust:

```
fake <- tibble(
  x = 0:100,
  a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1,
  e = 100 - .01*x^2,
) %>% gather(series, value, -x)

ggplot(fake, aes(x, value, fill = series)) + 
  # Left version has default borders
  geom_area(color = "black", lty = "solid") + # default seems to be size = 0.5
  # Right version has thin borders
  geom_area(aes(x+110), color = "black", lty = "solid", size = 0.2)
```

[image]